# Issue with Imperva WAF and IP Whitelisting on WordPress Site hosted on SiteGround

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, imperva

I am currently seeking guidance and assistance regarding an issue with Imperva Web Application Firewall (WAF) and IP whitelisting in the context of our WordPress application hosted on SiteGround.

We have implemented rules in our .htaccess file, which is located at /.htaccess, to whitelist Imperva's IP addresses. However, our website is currently facing accessibility problems due to the 'deny from all' statement in the .htaccess file, which seems to be blocking incoming traffic.

Here's the current configuration in our .htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [Imperva IP]
allow from [Imperva IP]
allow from [Imperva IP]

I'm seeking your guidance and recommendations on how to resolve this issue and configure IP whitelisting correctly for Imperva WAF in our specific hosting environment.

What are the best practices for whitelisting direct connections (original client IPs) from Imperva in the .htaccess file? Are there specific configuration settings or considerations we should be aware of, either in .htaccess or elsewhere?
```